# Apps Script - Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("SF Report");
var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

function inductionAssessment() {
var item = form.getItemById(260761081);
var values = wsData.getRange(2,13,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().filter(String);
item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
Logger.log(values);
}
```

[image: throwing null exceptions]

Hi! I have been trying to solve this but for some reason it keeps throwing this error, I have checked all the ID of the form, and they are all okay, any reason why this happening please?

How come this code work?

```
  var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("SF Report")
    var form = FormApp.openById(formID)
    
    function coachingAssessment() {
    var item = form.getItemById(401000225);
    var values = wsData.getRange(2,13,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().filter(String);
    item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
    Logger.log(values);
    }
```

Comment: The variable `item` is null. You're trying to get an item by id that doesn't exist.

Comment: @code there are lists of names in there, the other keys are working apart from this one.. so Im just confused

Comment: How did you obtain this ID? Did it work once then the next time throw an error?

Comment: @code I cant post the ID but it's a variable that I created, with the google form unique ID

Comment: In your script, I thought that when `console.log(form.getItems().findIndex(e => e.getId() == 260761081))` returns `-1`, it means that the item of the item ID is not existing.